# Create multiple .sh files using a loop

Tags: bash, unix

I want to prepare several .sh files to run some simulations.

Let's say that the command that I want to run multiple times is:

```
node_list = "Positive,Negative"

for nodes in $node_list; do
    python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation1.csv" -r "results_mutation1.csv"
done
```

where

- the_script is the script I want to run
- -m is the file to be used to run the simulation
- -r the file to save the results

I have a lists of mutants, so essentially I want to create loop that will give me
`mutant_list = [TP53, NFKB, ABL1]`

```
for nodes in $node_list; do
    python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation_TP53.csv" -r "results_mutation_TP53.csv"
done

for nodes in $node_list; do
    python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation_NFKB.csv" -r "results_mutation_NFKB.csv"
done

for nodes in $node_list; do
    python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation_ABL1.csv" -r "results_mutation_ABL1.csv"
done
```

and so on in one .sh file.

However, as I have 100 mutants I want to create a separate .sh file for each 5 mutants.

The expected output would be

`run_sim_1.sh` which contains (omitting the `for nodes in $node_list; do / done` for clarity)

```
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation1.csv" -r "results_mutation1.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation2.csv" -r "results_mutation2.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation3.csv" -r "results_mutation3.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation4.csv" -r "results_mutation4.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation5.csv" -r "results_mutation5.csv"
```

`run_sim_2.sh` which contains

```
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation6.csv" -r "results_mutation6.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation7.csv" -r "results_mutation7.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation8.csv" -r "results_mutation8.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation9.csv" -r "results_mutation9.csv"
python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m "file_mutation10.csv" -r "results_mutation10.csv"
```

Comment: Can't be this done with python too? Also what/where is `$node_list` coming from? A file,? stream? stdin?

Comment: Good point. I define the list at the sh file. I will update my question

Comment: Huh? None of your Python scripts receive either the node or the mutant?

Comment: Note that it's very unsafe to substitute data into a shell script unless you use an equivalent to Python's `shlex.quote()` to generate a safe version of that content. Double quotes are notably _not_ safe; `$(rm -rf ~).csv` is a perfectly legal filename on UNIX, but you don't want someone passing `"$(rm -rf ~).csv"` to your file. Neither is just blindly adding single quotes safe either: `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.csv` is _also_ a legal filename, and `'$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.csv'` is not safe to put on a shell command line.

Comment: Also, `node_list = "Positive,Negative"` is not a legal assignment in shell -- you can't have spaces around the `=`, and if you fix that, `for node in $node_list` will just set `node=Positive,Negative` because `,` is not a default part of `$IFS`. Maybe you want `node_list=( Positive Negative )` and then later `for nodes in "${node_list[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: BTW, bash 5.0 has `${var@Q}` as a way to generate a safely-escaped version of the data in `$var`.

Comment: That said... why generate code at all, instead of just having one constant script that reads a list of files to loop over? This seems like adding a bunch of potential for errors without much benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

node_list=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 )

counter=1
shcounter=1

for node in "${node_list[@]}"
do
    echo "python3.7 path_to_script/the_script -m \"file_mutation$node.sh\" -r \"results_mutation$node.csv\"" >>run_sim_${shcounter}.sh
    if [[ $counter -ge 5 ]]
    then
        (( shcounter = shcounter + 1 ))
        counter=0
    fi
    (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done
```

- I named the nodes 1,2,3,4,... just to show you that they are grouped 5 per .sh file, but they could have any name.  I do not take for granted that they follow a numeric sequence.  It will work with anything.
- variable `counter`: counts how many nodes have been processed in the `for` loop.
- variable `shcounter`: counts the number of .sh files that have been created.
- each time a node is processed, the command with that node is written to the current .sh file (current is designated by the shcounter).  Also the counter is incremented.  If it is greater than 5, it is reset to 0, and the shcounter is incremented.

Running this script creates 3 files.  run_sim1.sh (nodes 1->5), runsim2.sh (nodes 6->10), runsim3.sh (node 11).  I wanted something not divisible by 5 to show my algorithm could handle it.